# Send/Receive in easynetq with persistance layer

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, easynetq

I have a quick question, I am using easy net and I want to use in a couple of cases send/receive pattern as it stands in documentation: https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Send-Receive but I don't see information if I'll set message to be persistent, in case on one of the endpoint reset (for example my endpoint restarts after sending but did not receive response yet), after the reset will I receive that response?